# SQL Server Query runs slow when placed inside of a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a query that I am putting in to a stored procedure.  When I run the query with local variables the query takes ~1 second to run. When I put the same query inside of a stored procedure and call the SP, it takes around 2 minutes to run.

From previous questions in SO I think it may be related to parameter sniffing.  When I've had this issue before I have declared local variables inside my SP and then used the local variables throughout.  This has worked in the past, but does not seem to help me in this case.

I currently have

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.ProcedureName

    @DIV VARCHAR(4),
    @STD VARCHAR(1), -- S or N
    @scen varchar(20)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE 
        @DIV_copy VARCHAR(4),
        @STD_copy VARCHAR(1),
        @scen_copy varchar(20);
    SELECT
        @DIV_copy = @DIV,
        @STD_copy = @STD,
        @scen_copy = @scen;
```

I have also tried adding `WITH RECOMPILE` like so

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.ProcedureName

    @DIV VARCHAR(4),
    @STD VARCHAR(1), -- S or N
    @scen varchar(20)

WITH RECOMPILE
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE 
        @DIV_copy VARCHAR(4),
        @STD_copy VARCHAR(1),
        @scen_copy varchar(20);
    SELECT
        @DIV_copy = @DIV,
        @STD_copy = @STD,
        @scen_copy = @scen;
```

Additionally, I have tried adding the `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` at the end of my SP like so:

```
SELECT *
    FROM #Output

OPTION(RECOMPILE)

END
GO
```

I also tried using:

```
OPTION(OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN )
```

As well as:

```
OPTION(QUERYTRACEON 4136)
```

On this option, I do not have appropriate permissions for query tracing.

None of the 5 fixes above appear to fix the issue as the stored procedure still takes anywhere between 2 minutes and 2 minutes and 30 seconds for the same query that takes 1 or 2 seconds outside of the stored procedure.

These fixes all came from this article '[Different Approaches to Correct SQL Server Parameter Sniffing](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3257/different-approaches-to-correct-sql-server-parameter-sniffing/)'

Has anyone had similar issues?  Thank you for your time!

SQL Server 2008R2

Comment: It does sound like parameter sniffing, and I don't have any other idea what it could be.  You could check this article to see if it offers any additional solutions that you haven't already tried:  http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html

Comment: `I have tried adding the OPTION(RECOMPILE) at the end of my SP` - it should be placed after the offending query. But if `with recompile` didn't work I doubt this correction will.

Comment: I have had the exact same symptoms and creating local copies of params has always solved it. The only difference is that I have always used a SET statement instead of a SELECT statement to copy values into the local variables.

Comment: i have been in similar situation one, to resolve that i tweak the query thus change in query plan to resolve that, can you share the Actual query plan  and query.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I did not figure out why the same exact query had so much trouble when placed inside a stored procedure when compared to the sql statements alone.

As a "workaround" I spent some time optimizing my queries within the SP.  I realized one table I was joining to was very large (millions and millions of rows) so what I did was grab the relevant data from the large table and created a temp table to hold it, then joined to the (much) smaller temp table and that seemed to do the trick.  The SP is executing in 3-4 seconds now.

I am still somewhat new to SQL outside of the basics so I am learning a lot.  Let this serve as a reminder to scrutinize your queries, there's often room for improvement.  This feels somewhat like scotch tape and paperclips, but my problem was solved.

Thank you everyone for your input.

Comment: Rather than a temp table, you'll likely do better by adding an index to the large table that matches the join conditions.

Comment: True but I do not have permissions to do that, though I could ask our DBA team perhaps.